# Test Goodness of fit for FindFit

Tags: fitting

Is there any way to get an estimate of the goodness of fit from FindFit, for instance getting the final error? The documentation doesn't provide any hints, and a quick Google search didn't return any useful link either. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: A discussion of quantifying the quality of fits, including the error residuals, appears here:  tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `NonlinearModelFit` instead of `FindFit`.

```
dt = Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}];
FindFit[dt, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x]
(* {a -> 1.42076, b -> 1.65558, c -> 0.534645} *)

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dt, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x];
Normal[nlm]
(* 1.42076 x Log[1.65558+0.534645 x]*)

nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Transpose[{#, nlm[#]} &[{"AdjustedRSquared", "AIC", "BIC", "RSquared"}]], Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

See: [NonlinearModelFit >> Properties >> Goodness of fit measures](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)

Comment: Two tiny questions if I may: -1- I am using `nlm["ParameterTable"]` as well after a nonlinearModelFit, but I get a warning that `"The property values {"ParameterTable"} assume an unconstrained model..." probably because I added a constraint while fitting, has this happened to you as well? -2- Is there a built-in way of also estimating the [chi-squared per degree of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic#Definition) for the fit? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `NMinimize` function for fitting. Just minimize chi-square_nu over the parameter space to find your parameters.